# Is the division symbol $\div$ acceptable based on international standards?

Tags: notation, arithmetic, binary-operations

The division symbol $\div$ is found in almost all calculators; however, I seldom see it in any formal writing. It seems people almost exclusively prefer $\frac{a}{b}$, $a/b$ or $ab^{-1}$ to $a\div b$. Is the symbol $\div$ considered outdated today? Is it all right to use it in formal writtings (for example, denote $ab^{-1}$ by $a\div b$ when $a$ and $b$ are elements in a field such that $b\neq 0$)?

**Edit**: Since the question was on hold since it is "opinion based", I would like to reask my question in the following way:

*Is the usuage of the symbol $\div$ in professional mathematical writtings acceptable based on objective international standards, such as [ISO 80000-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_80000-2)?*

Comment: But $\div$ is just $\frac{a}{b}$ with the bullets replaced by $a$ and $b$: $$\frac{\bullet}{\bullet}=\frac{a}{b}$$.

Comment: I feel its just because the $\div$ symbol is inconvenient

Comment: Even if it's never used beyond a certain level, I can't see primary schools giving up on it.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, I teach college classes and I do not use $\div$ frequently; on the other hand, I also do not shun this notation. Is there any standard suggestion from some authorities, such as ISO 80000 specification?

Comment: Thanks @Jean-ClaudeArbaut! In fact, $\div$ can still be found even in very advanced scientific calculators. I am also wondering when one studies some algebraic structure, if an operation needs to be defined which is alnalogous to division of real numbers, people ever thought about using $\div$.

Comment: @Zuriel I think at least some calculators do use it to distinguish between a division operation and a fraction—for example my Casio fx-991es has both a ÷ key and a fraction key, and when the fraction key is used it refuses to return a decimal value if it can return a fraction.

Comment: I think your original question was pretty reasonable (though it could use some clarification about what sort of "formal writing" you are talking about) but the current version about international standards is off-topic.

Comment: @EricWofsey, the original one was on hold as opinion based and thus I tried to edit it.

Comment: See for a brief discussion of division notation: https://xkcd.com/2687/

Answer (score 2):

The $\div$ symbol is outdated and should be avoided.

Quoting from Florian Cajori's book [A History of Mathematical Notations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486677664).
(Volume I, Chapter III, Part B, Paragraph $243$ A critical Estimate of $:$ and $\div$ as Symbols)

> In 1923 the National Committee on Mathematical Requirements voiced the following opinion:
>
> > "Since neither $\div$ nor $:$, as signs of division plays any part in business life, it seems proper to consider only the needs of algebra, and to make more use of the fractional form and (where meaning is clear) of the symbol $/$, and to drop the symbol $\div$ in writing algebraic expressions."

Comment: Thank you! The opinion you quoted is 95 years old; is this opinion outdated? :-)

Comment: @Zuriel  The opinion would be outdated if the majority of current mathematicians thinks it is outdated.  I haven't met a mathematician who uses $\div$ even once in a while within the past ten years, so let's that speak for itself.  This notation can only be seen in low level math, and sometimes on youtube.

Comment: Thanks! So the conclusion is, $\div$ is outdated today; furthermore, it was outdated 95 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Not a definitive answer, but my feeling is that ÷ says "We are doing arithmetic on actual numerical values", so it might be useful in helping non-mathematical readers to follow what's happening, or if you want to distinguish between the division result and the process of getting it.

Example: as a child, it was a revelation to me that $$2÷3=\frac23,$$ ie that *two thirds are the same as a third of 2,* and that making a fraction is the same as dividing two numbers.

It seemed like magic! Suddenly I didn't have to work out that there were $6$ thirds in $2$ and divide that by $3$ to get two of
them—I could just put one number above the other and have the answer.

The same distinction is expressed in the terminology. ÷ has a *divisor* by which the *dividend* is *divided*, while the fraction has a *numerator* *"enumerating"*  the subunits used and a *denominator* specifying the *"denomination"* or kind of subunit.

So they do signify slightly different concepts—it's just that most of the time, the difference isn't relevant and we're better off ignoring it.

**Edit:** Here's the conceptual difference expressed visually.
[image: drawing of a pair of rectangles together, with one third shaded, then one on its own with two thirds shaded]